# Exclusão lógica de registros do SQL Server

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server, desempenho, tsql

Temos a cultura de fazer somente exclusões lógicas na aplicação, mantendo 2 campos onde 1 é a data de exclusão e outro um char que recebe 'S' ou 'N'.

Quando executamos buscas por registros não excluídos, fazemos algo do tipo:

```
select * from tb where exc = 'N'
```

Tendo em vista que temos 2 campos para indicar a mesma coisa (se está excluído ou não), minha pergunta é a seguinte:

O que é mais performático? Fazer a consulta como já está sendo feita ou evoluir para algo deste tipo:

```
select * from tb where dat_exc is not null
```

O objetivo é manter apenas a data de exclusão.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Este tipo de coisa é difícil responder em definitivo. Cada situação é diferente. Mesmo na sua aplicação o que pode ser bom hoje pode não ser amanhã por uma mudança de hardware, de versão do banco de dados, padrão de uso, etc. Só medindo para dizer ao certo. Então como qualquer medição que eu faça não vai lhe servir nem vou perder tempo.

Provavelmente você quer saber o que intuitivamente tem melhor desempenho. Então vou dizer que é a forma como você está fazendo. Comparar um caractere tende a ser mais rápido que comparar uma data que além de ser um dado maior provavelmente precisará de verificações (se é `null`, por exemplo) e conversões extras. Mas eu perdi as contas de quantas vezes o que era intuitivo se mostrou errado. Então só posso reforçar para fazer o teste com ambas.

Sugeriria testar se muda alguma coisa usar a coluna `exc` como `null` ou ter um valor. Ou mudá-la para um tipo `bit` e ver o que acontece em cada situação nas principais *queries* que você costuma usar.

Estes bancos de dados possuem uma quantidade incomensurável de monitoramentos, estatísticas, perfilamentos justamente porque eles são muito úteis e necessários.

Talvez no seu caso nem seja tão necessário assim e a diferença é tão pequena que não deveria nem se preocupar. Se você tem algum gargalo provavelmente está em outro lugar. E se não tem, a preocupação é exagerada. Pense nisto.

Particularmente eu optaria por ter só a data até que isto se mostrasse problemático.

Comment: Mas se eu manter só a data, terei um campo com valores nulos (não excluídos) e neste caso não seria possível indexar, ou seria?

Comment: Depende de como você vai fazer. Mas não vejo porque não poderia indexar. Existência de nulos não impede indexação. Não vejo porque a existência de um campo extra vá ajudar. "Não vejo" não significa que não tenha, eu posso só não estar vendo, talvez por não saber exatamente o que você está fazendo. De qualquer forma você já tem isto hoje. E nem falei ainda se não valeria você usar [índices filtrados ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280372.aspx) porque não sei se seria útil para você neste caso.